# create DataManager class which only downloads/creates datasets once called and not yet created

Tags: python, database, oop, iterator

So I'm working on bettering my OO skills, and am working on a project which requires working with different datasets. I have three datasets, let's call them `first_data`, `second_data` and `third_data`. I download these from their respective sources and save these into `pandas.DataFrame`s with a method for each datasets called `make_*_data()` with `*` replacing the name of the data.

I have a class build called `DataManager` which looks as follows:

```
class DataManager:
    """ Manages the datasets for this project.

    TODO: add caching method to check for already downloaded files.
    TODO: apply Singleton pattern to this class
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._first_data = None
        self._second_data = None
        self._third_data = None

    @property
    def first_data(self):
        if self._first_data is None:
            self._first_data = make_first_data()
        return self._first_data

    @property
    def second_data(self):
        if self._first_data is None:
            self._first_data = make_second_data()
        return self._first_data

    @property
    def third_data(self):
        if self._first_data is None:
            self._first_data = make_third_data()
        return self._first_data
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure if this is a nice way, but this seems to do the trick. However, I now want to perform actions for each data set that I have, like training a kNN model. I want something like looping over all datasets, and have looked into using `__getattr__` or `__getitem__`, but I'm a bit lost in the forest here so I'm looking for advice.

My goal is to have something working among the lines of:

```
for dataset in DataManager.datasets:
    # perform action for dataset
```

And I'm looking for a nice, clean way to implement this. I have tried defining

```
# the __init__
    self._datasets = {
        "first_data": self._first_data,
        "second_data": self._second_data,
        "third_data": self._third_data
    }

# the properties

def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self._datasets[item]
```

But this doesn't work since it will return `None`. I can replace all the items in `DataManager.datasets` with the properties instead of the private attributes, but that will just run all the downloading at time of the initialization which I want to avoid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an alternative approach by subclassing a dict
(note: a `UserDict` wraps a `dict`).

You can also adapt it to conform to your desired class interface (not done here):

```
from collections import UserDict

class Datasets(UserDict):
    def _load(self, key):
        # load data for this specific key
        print("Loading data...")
        return "loaded {} data from somewhere".format(key)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = self._load(key)
        return self[key]

datasets = Datasets()

print(datasets["first"])
print(datasets["second"])
print()
print(datasets["first"])
print()
print(datasets)
print()
for dataset in datasets.values():
    print(dataset) # process dataset
```

Output:

```
Loading data...
loaded first data from somewhere
Loading data...
loaded second data from somewhere

loaded first data from somewhere

{'first': 'loaded first data from somewhere', 'second': 'loaded second data from somewhere'}

loaded first data from somewhere
loaded second data from somewhere
```

Of course you have to process the case of not being able to load a dataset, or having the wrong dataset name/key specified.

Comment: Thank you for this, this looks like a nice way to implementing this. I'll try it!

Comment: @GroenteLepel, you are welcome, It looked simpler to me too.